# Moles and AppSettingsReader?

Tags: c#, moles

I'm working with Moles to write some unit tests.  I searched online but I don't see any responses on how to use Moles to intercept the calls to AppSettingsReader.GetValue.

Has anyone been able to do this using Moles?  Or am I forced into isolating the calls in my own class I can inject or mock?  Ideally there is a way to directly use Moles to intercept the calls because we don't really want to modify the code we're looking to put under test.

Thanks!

Comment: For what its worth I ended up wrapping the call:

    public class AppSettings
    {
        public object GetValue(string key, Type type)
        {
            return new AppSettingsReader().GetValue(key, type);
        }
    }

I would still like to find a solution though as I prefer not to modify the code I want to put under test.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I strongly recommend moving to the release version of Moles, called "Fakes and Stubs", in .NET 4.5 / C# 5 / Visual Studio 2012.

The System.Configurations namespace is incompatible with the Mole/Fake type, and must be stubbed. To create a stub using the Moles Framework, simply create an interface for the System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader type.  The Moles compiler will automatically convert the interface into a Stub type.

Here's an interface you can add to your project:

```
using System;

namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE_HERE
{
  /// <summary>
  /// IOC object for stubbing System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader.
  /// Provides a method for reading values of a particular type from
  /// the configuration.
  /// </summary>
  interface IAppSettingsReader
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value for a specified key from the
    /// System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings property
    /// and returns an object of the specified type containing the
    /// value from the configuration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key for which to get the value.</param>
    /// <param name="type">The type of the object to return.</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the specified key</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">key is null.
    /// - or -
    /// type is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">key does
    /// not exist in the &lt;appSettings&gt; configuration section.
    /// - or -
    /// The value in the &lt;appSettings&gt; configuration section
    /// for key is not of type type.</exception>
    public object GetValue(string key, Type type);
  }
}
```

Here's a stub class, too:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE_HERE
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Production stub for System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader.
  /// Provides a method for reading values of a particular type from
  /// the configuration.
  /// </summary>
  public class AppSettingsReaderStub : IAppSettingsReader
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value for a specified key from the
    /// System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings property
    /// and returns an object of the specified type containing the value
    /// from the configuration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key for which to get the value.</param>
    /// <param name="type">The type of the object to return.</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the specified key</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">key is null.
    /// - or -
    /// type is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">key does not
    /// exist in the &lt;appSettings&gt; configuration section.
    /// - or -
    /// The value in the &lt;appSettings&gt; configuration section for
    /// key is not of type type.</exception>
    public object GetValue(string key, Type type)
    {
      var reader = new AppSettingsReader();
      object result = reader.GetValue(key, type);
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't use F&M yet since VS 2012 is not releasd and I don't expect we will be using it this year.

Thanks for the information on stubbing, that might come in useful if I'm in a injection model. Given the code base I can't use a stub for this set of tests.